# Leaflet zoom to attribute when click on button

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, leaflet, zooming

New to Leaflet and need a lot of assistance. I want to be able to click on a button and it will zoom to an attribute on my map. Example would be council districts. Say, I click on the button that says Council district 2, I want to to zoom to that district and highlight it. How is this possible in Leaflet? So far all i have is this:

```
<div class="push-top">
    <button class="cc-bttn"  onclick="buttonClick('bttn1')">CC 1</button>
    <button class="cc-bttn"  onclick="buttonClick('bttn2')">CC 2</button>
    <button class="cc-bttn"  onclick="buttonClick('bttn3')">CC 3</button>
    <button class="cc-bttn"  onclick="buttonClick('bttn4')">CC 4</button>
</div>


<script>
function buttonClick(str){
  alert(str)
}
```

This creates a popup box, not what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share some more code showing how the map and the features are set up.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a array of markers and then get the marker with latlng by the name and then pan the map to the latlng.

```
var markers =  [];
markers['bttn1'] = L.marker([lat,lng]).addTo(map);
markers['bttn2'] = L.marker([lat,lng]).addTo(map);
markers['bttn3'] = L.marker([lat,lng]).addTo(map);

var zoom = 15;
function buttonClick(str){
  var marker = markers[str];
  var latlng = marker.getLatLng();
  map.flyTo(latlng,zoom)
}
```